# MongoDB Aggregation : Append a value ton an array

Tags: python, mongodb

I want a mongodb aggregation pipeline to transform

```
{ "a": "1", "b": ["2", "3"] }
```

to

```
{ "c": ["1", "2", "3"] }
```

something like `$concatArrays` but with single values and array

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with concatArrays. However you will have to wrap the single values into arrays with "[]"

[mongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MULiFh6M8qN)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "c": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          ["$a"],
          "$b"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```